# UiTouches on scroll view not working, How to set zoom in pain app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitouch, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I have implemented **a paint application using UITouches** by following ***`RayWenderlich`*** tutorial

[**Make A Simple Drawing App with UIKit**](http://www.raywenderlich.com/18840/how-to-make-a-simple-drawing-app-with-uikit)

I completed my paint successfully.

But **I need to set zoomin and zoom out functionalitie**s,

So that i added my ImageViews on UIScrollView.

But the **paint is not working due to UITouches not working on UIScrollView**.

---

```
I know due to scrollable behavior touches are are not working,
But even after i disable the scrollable option its did not works.
```

---

I implemented **zooming functionality with Pinch Guesters but, it is not able to see out side zoomed, its just able to see zoomed image with in the window.**

Can anybody suggest me how to handle perfect zoom in paint application

Comment: Question is a little hard to understand. You should add a magnifier image or something, which disables drawing and enables zooming, so the gestures don't get confused.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the below touch methods on the UIScrollView

• touchesBegan

• touchesEnded

• touchesMoved

• touchesCancelled

then you need to subclass your UIScrollView and then you can implement all these mehods:

Cheers!!